# Facebook Comments - current page URL

Tags: facebook

Is there any way the Facebook Comments box can use the current page's URL?  I want to add the feature to my site but don't want the same comments showing on each page.  For example, I want the comments for "article1" to only show with "article1."  The comments for "article2" would only show with "article2" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook comment plugin is url based.  You would need to set href or data-href property with unique urls for each article that you want to have unique comments on.